# how to include conditional statements in FortranForm?

Tags: formatting, fortran

how to to include following formula in the FortranForm in a correct format?

```
R = 
  Compile[{{y}}, 
    Piecewise[{{1.31446 Tan[1.58986 y] + 0.91209 y, 
       Abs[y] < 0.84136}, {1./(Sign[y] - y), 
       0.841360 <= Abs[y] < 1.}}], 
    RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False 
    , Parallelization -> True, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"] //FullSimplify;
 DR=D[R[a],a];
FortranForm[DR]
```

Comment: I don't know of any code to create Fortran from WL compiled code, but perhaps you could use [CCodeGenerate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCodeGenerator/tutorial/Overview) instead to create C code?

Comment: @CarlWoll  how about uncompiled version of the code... unfortunately the code is in fortran :)

Comment: Applying `D` to your function `R` is meaningless. If you want to see the C-code for `R`, use `ExportString[R,"C"]`. You have to search a bit for the relevant part of the code, though. Afterwards, you can easily translate it to fortran by hand (at least the standard arithmetics can be copied)...

Comment: Can’t you call a C function from Fortran?

Comment: can you explain better what you are actually trying to do? I cant see any reason to use `Compile` at all if the goal is to create fortran code.

Comment: @CarlWoll possibly but i have not done that thanks anyways

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher may i ask why applying D to R is meaningless since we both get the same result? DR/.{y->0.2} or yours DR[0.2]?

Comment: @george2079 please ignore the compile part. R[y_] := 
  Block[{}, $Pre = 
    Function[Null, 
     Unevaluated[#] /. 
      r_Real?MachineNumberQ :> RuleCondition@SetPrecision[r, 16], 
     HoldAllComplete]; 
   Piecewise[{{1.31446 Tan[1.58986 y] + 0.91209 y, 
      Abs[y] < 0.84136}, {1./(Sign[y] - y), 0.841360 <= Abs[y] < 1.}}];

Comment: @user49047 Ah, interesting. Usually, `D` is a symbolical derivative. Seemingly it is overloaded by a numerical derivative for `CompiledFunction` s. I guess so because the difference to the "true" derivative at point `0.2` is `9.35785*10^-10`; while this is completely acceptable for numerical purposes, it is a bit too much for a symbolic derivative. Note that the symbolic expression for `R` is encapsulated in the `CompiledFunction`  `DR` (try `DR1[[0, 1, -3]]`), so that _in principle_, a symbolic derivative would also be possible.

Comment: @user49047 This means that `D` has no effect on the compiled code; it computes the derivative numerically at runtime. So, even if `DR=D[R[a],a];` might work for cumpoting a numerical derivative, calling `FortranForm[DR]` afterwards is meaningless: `FortranForm` just takes the expresion of the `CompiledFunction` `R` in `FullForm` and applies certain transformation rules (replacing `[` and `]` by `(` and `)`, respectively, shuffling in some `*` for multiplication, and ... well, in this case, that's it).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher the funny thing is that still neither numerical nor exact are not really correct. the exact derivative of this function is  exactinvde[x_] := 1./(1./(R[x])^2 - 1./(Sinh[R[x]])^2) one can also change Sign function to sign[x_] := 2 HeavisideTheta[x] - 1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is simple enough to do by hand..you will spend more time trying to automate the process than just typing the code out.

First a little manipulation of the original expression to get rid of the `Abs`

```
cons = {
  c1 -> 1.31446,
  c2 -> 1.58986,
  c3 -> 0.91209,
  c4 -> 0.84136}
dp = Piecewise[
  {{c1 Tan[c2 y] + c3 y, Abs[y] < c4},
   {1/(1 - y), c4 <= y < 1},
   {-1/(1 + y), -1 < y <= -c4 }}]
dd = D[dp, y]
```

[image]

here you can use `FortranForm` to pull out parts of the expression:

```
  FortranForm[dd[[1, 1, 1]]]
```

> c3 + c1*c2*Sec(c2*y)**2

just do that as needed and paste to the code as you write:

```
    real function df(y)
    implicit none
    real::y
    real,parameter::c1=1.31446,c2=1.58986,c3=0.91209,c4=0.84136
    if(abs(y).gt.1)then
      df=0
    elseif( y.le.-c4)then
      df=(1+y)**(-2)
    elseif(y.gt.c4)then
      df=(1-y)**2
    else
      df=c3 + c1*c2*Sec(c2*y)**2
    endif
   end
```

Comment: @geogerge2079, how can we define real*8 value: e.g. 1.d0, 2.d0 etc??? it could be useful in fortran coding